# centos 7 open port is open but not working

Tags: linux, centos, port

**centos 7 open port is open but not working**

t try to open port on my vps centos 7  like 5060

this port is just number  i need it open in my system

i open it in iptables  and firewall-cmd

```
2004h[root@centos ~]# sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0 eth1
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client http https ssh telnet
  ports: 5060/tcp 80/tcp 443/tcp
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

now on i check port using https://portchecker.co/check the port is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some countries port 5060 is blocked by ISP
what i understand you opened the port in your virtual machine.
you need to open the port in VPS host panel security group as well.